# AngularJS watchCollection with scope variables and an array

Tags: angularjs

In my controller I have some scope variables like

```
$scope.searchText = "abc";
$scope.currentPage ="1";
$scope.sortBy ="dateTime";
$scope.sortOrder="reverse";

$scope.columnSettings = [
                        {"name": "dateTime, 
                         "displayName": "Datetime",     
                         "filterText": ""
                        },
                        {"name": "name, 
                         "displayName": "Name", 
                         "filterText": "xyz"
                        },
                        {"name": "id, 
                         "displayName": "ID", 
                         "filterText": ""
                       }]
```

I need to watch on all the $scope variables and "filterText" key of the objects in "columnSettings" array.

I am using

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[searchText, sortBy, sortOrder, currentPage, itemsPerPage, columnSettings]', function(newVal, oldVal){
                    // Ignore initial scope change
                    if(oldVal && newVal !== oldVal){

                        // watch is triggered for changes in searchText, sortBy etc...
// but not for "filterText" change in columnSettings
                    }
                });
```

My question is

a)  watch is triggered for changes in searchText, sortBy, currentPage etc...but not for "filterText" change in columnSettings. How can I solve this?

b) also, I want to trigger watch only on "filterText" key change and not on any changes to the other keys.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You *really* shouldn't have to watch all of these.  If you bind them to a template a `watch` is created for you anyway (this is two-way binding).  I'm curious to know why you think you need to watch everything like this. :)

Comment: All these values are bound to template can be changed by the user. For every change, I need to manipulate couple of values and make http.get call to the backend. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: For "every key press in searchText" you are going to make an http call?  This doesn't sound very nice.  If you *trigger* the http call somehow (like with a button click) maybe that is a better place to arrange the data before calling the server.  However, without more code (like the HTML template) it is impossible to comment further.

Comment: Yes, that's the requirement I have.  Need to make $http.GET for every change.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing `filterText` is populated by an input on your web page.
In that case you should use an `ng-change` attribute in the template (on each input), and this can trigger an event handler on your `$scope`.
As Davin noted in the comments, what you are trying to do is usually a bad idea (except maybe in some rare cases I cannot picture).

Comment: Yes, `ng-change` makes sure that the dirty check is only triggered by a UI change and therefore doesn't involve the digest loop continuously.

Comment: If your event handler is to fetch data on a server, you'll also want to use throttling (typically: only call the server after the input has not been edited in the last second)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get notified on changes on one of the object's properties you could simply add `$watch` as follows:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('columnSettings', function (obj) {
    // handle obj.filterText change
});
```

You can not add `columnSettings` to `$watchCollection` as it's a collection itself, so it unfortunately has to be watched on it's own.

Comment: columnSettings is an Array. Can $watch be used this way ? That seems a bit funny (is this watching all `filterText`s inside the objects in the array ?)

Comment: I was hoping to have one place where I can watch all the variables and avoid not having both $watchCollection and $watch.  Also, columnSettings is an array. Not sure if I can use columnSettings.filterText.

Comment: @user3701057, one thing to keep in mind with Angular is that using $watch ends up being quite expensive when they all add up. We should avoid using it whenever possible. Angular already adds some $watch for you through the template binding.

Comment: Yep folks, you're right. @user3701057 i don't think that you can reduce it to one watch call. Check my edited answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing like this.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[searchText, sortBy, sortOrder, currentPage, itemsPerPage]', function(newVal, oldVal){
```

});

and use $watch for columnSettings and watch only "filterText" changes

```
$scope.$watch(function($scope) {
                    return $scope.columnSettings.
                        map(function(obj) {
                            return obj.filterText
                        });
                }, function(newVal, oldVal){
});
```